# C++ Stack around variable is corrupted

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

I am trying to implement a timer, which takes a function pointer as a parameter and a time in milliseconds. After the time is passed, the function should be called in a separate thread. The code looks as follows:

```
class timer
{
public:
    void schedule(void(*function)(), int time)
    {
        std::thread t = std::thread([&]
            {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(time));
                function(); 
            });
        t.detach();
    }
};
```

The main method looks as follows:

```
#define LOG(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;


timer t1;
timer t2;
timer t3;
t1.schedule([] {LOG("t1 done")}, 2000);
t2.schedule([] {LOG("t2 done")}, 3000);
t3.schedule([] {LOG("t3 done")}, 4000);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));
```

The exception is as follows:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 't1' was corrupted.
```

Comment: The only thing I can see that could be an issue is you capture by reference with your lambda.  That gives `time` a chance to go out of scope before it is used in the thread.  Try capturing by value and see what happens.  `[&] -> [=]`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply NathanOliver. This solved the problem :)

Comment: No problem.  I wrote up a litle more detailed answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is you are capturing by reference in your lambda.  This means that it is possible for you to call `detach` and exit from `schedule` before the `operator()` of the lambda is called.  If that happens then when you try to use `time` you are accessing a dangling reference.

The solution here is to capture by value instead.  This means you get a copy and it doesn't matter when the `operator()` is called as the lambda doesn't rely on anything.